# How to send a object variable into method which calls dowork by BackgroundWorker instance?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I saw createobjref property when I used the BackgroundWorker class. I am trying that send a object variable into method which calls dowork. thus, I will find out which BackgroundWorker instance calls method.

I left a code snippet below for you to learn better

```
            bw_daily = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw_daily.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw_daily.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw_daily.DoWork += bw_daily_DoWork;
            bw_daily.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_daily_WorkerCompleted;
    
            bw_daily_2 = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw_daily_2.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw_daily_2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw_daily_2.DoWork += bw_daily_DoWork;
            bw_daily_2.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_daily_WorkerCompleted;
```

calling method;

```
protected void bw_daily_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

I think createobjref might be useful to solve my problem but I don't find detailed information on microsoft documentation or anywhere.

Finally If you have better solution for me please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem that way;

I've created a class, which inherited BackGroundWorker and added a bool property.

```
    class CustomBackGroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
    {
        public DateTime RunDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public TimeSpan Period
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Exception Exception
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool IsOrganization
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

And then I have just called and used;

```
CustomBackGroundWorker bw_daily = new CustomBackGroundWorker();
bw_daily.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bw_daily.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
bw_daily.DoWork += bw_daily_DoWork;
bw_daily.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_daily_WorkerCompleted;
bw_daily.IsOrganization = true;
```